# C++ : using nlohmann json in project

Tags: c++, nlohmann-json

I am trying to  use [nlohmann json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) in my C++ project. I extracted the zipped file after I downloaded it from github. I renamed the extracted folder to be `nlohmann_json` and just copied it inside my project .

The github doc says :

*json.hpp is the single required file in single_include/nlohmann or released here. You need to add*

```
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

// for convenience
using json = nlohmann::json;
```

So in my `.cpp` file, I have the following lines :

```
#include "nlohmann_json/include/nlohmann/json.hpp"

using json = nlohmann::json;
```

But Visual Studio 2015 IDE shows as tooltip the following message:

**namespace nlohmann has no member json**

After typing just `nlohmann::` , I get an auto suggestion of `json_pointer` but not `json`.

What is going wrong actually ?

Comment: hm...according to the json.hpp the actual class is named "basic_json"

Comment: @skeller, the doc asks to use `using json = nlohmann::json;`. I edited my question.

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed Sure about `#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>` and not `#include "nlohmann/json.hpp"`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, not clear what you said .

Comment: <single_include/nlohmann/json.hpp>
this seems to be the correct file according to documentation

Comment: @skeller, then it says :`cannot open source file "nlohmann_json/include/nlohmann/json.hpp"`

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed Adjust your include search paths using the `-I` compiler flags properly.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, how to do that in Visual Studio 2015 ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed I think for MSVC toolchain the appropriate compiler  flag is `/I`

Answer (score 6):

You actually have a hint to your problem.

```
json.hpp is the single required file in single_include/nlohmann or released here. You need to add
```

If you go to the original tree you checked out from github, and do this:

```
$ find . -name json.hpp
./include/nlohmann/json.hpp
./single_include/nlohmann/json.hpp
```

You might see your problem. You're including the first of the found files. You really need the second one -OR- you need to set up includes search path better.

Here's what I would do. I would copy ./single_include/nlohmann/json.hpp into the project. I would NOT include the entire tree, just that file. And include it.

I think that will work better for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the single header approach where you can directly include the single json.hpp (inside the single_include, just drop nlohmann/json.hpp at the root of your project).  Or if you want to include the one that have multiple files then you will need to set additional include headers in your VS project settings.

```
MyProj
  nlohmann\....
  main.cpp
```

Then in your VS project settings add the path to your project to the additional include directories.

Comment: 'you will need to set additional include headers in your VS project settings' - can you elaborate ?

Comment: If you go to your VS project properties settings (right click on your project in VS and click properties, then under C/C++, General) there is a property for you to specify additional include directories.

Comment: should additional include directories point to the root of nlohmann scripts ?

Comment: You want to set the path up to the directory that the nlohmann folder is in (so something like .../myproject and not .../myproject/nlohmann).  The reason for this is that you're going to include it as "nlohmann/json.hpp", as well as other files in the nlohmann library so you want to leave out the nlohmann folder in your include path in the VS setting.  All what we're doing here is let your compiler know of additional path to search for include headers.